# How to find inverse of summation for inverse transform sampling?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation, summation-method

How can I find the inverse of summation for this

> $u=\sum_{h=1}^{n-j} {n-j \choose h}(-1)^h \; \frac{1}{j+h} 
> > (1-e^{-\lambda_1X})^{\alpha \alpha_1(j+h)}$

where $x>0 , \alpha, \alpha_1 >0$

I want to find X alone in left hand side like this

$U=F(x)$ and I want to get X  equals the inverse function of U,$\;\;$ $X=F^{-1}(U)$ , see the following example

$U=(1-e^{-\lambda_1X})^{\alpha \alpha_1}$

$U^{\frac{1}{\alpha \alpha_1}}=1-e^{-\lambda_1X}$

$1-U^{\frac{1}{\alpha \alpha_1}}=e^{-\lambda_1X}$

$ln(1-U^{\frac{1}{\alpha \alpha_1}})=-\lambda_1X$

$X=\frac{ln(1-U^{\frac{1}{\alpha \alpha_1}})}{-\lambda_1}$

How can I do that in my expression?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Manal! The formula you wrote for the summation seems to have some problems. Consider changing exp^{..} to e^{..} or \exp(...). Also, what are $\alpha$ and $\alpha_1.$ Finally, you should explain what you have tried so far, and maybe add a bit of context to the question.

Comment: @Kore-N Thanks for improving my question, I edited.

Comment: U is a variable follow uniform [0,1]